# EmberJs - Computed Properties and Template

Tags: javascript, ember.js

The problem is that i can't correctly display the changes i make to an ember property.

Here's the action:

```
toggle_favorites: function() {
      var favorite = this.get('some_service').get("favorites");
      this.set("favorite", favorite);
      if (favorite.length > 0) {
        this.set("hasFavorites", true);
      }
     // show some feedback, irrelevant
    },
```

after that i just display everything as a list

```
{{#each favorite}} ...
```

The problem is that if i keep adding stuff to the list, the changes won't be reflected in the hbs file.

I tried using a computed property as follows

```
  favs: Ember.computed("hasFavorites", "some_service.favorites", "favorite.length", function() {
      return this.get("favorite");
  }).property('@favorite.length'),
```

and display that, but with no avail. 
If i add something to the list, and then trigger my action it's successful, but every sequential addition won't be displayed.

I'm using Ember 2.6.

Comment: Maybe can you provide a not-working `ember-twiddle`?

Answer (score 0):

I have some weird fix

i'm using

```
  this.set("favorite", null);
  this.set("favorite", favorite);
```

and

```
favs: Ember.computed("favorite.[]", function() {
    return this.get("favorite");
  }),
```

Setting the favorite property as null, seem to do the trick, although i can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

@Rentonie, use `favorite.length` or `favorite.@each.someprop`
Try

```
favs: Ember.computed("favorite.length", function() {
   return this.get("favorite");
}),
```

or

```
favs: Ember.computed("favorite.@each.someprop", function() {
   return this.get("favorite");
}),
```